# Jquery Live Form Validation

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, validation, live

I'm currently using this plugin to perform live form validation 
[GeekTantra](http://www.geektantra.com/2009/09/jquery-live-form-validation/)

This is working well and is validating all of my form fields bar one.

I'm trying to see if a username entered into a field matches a value in an array and if it does return a 'username is already in use' message.  The data is being collected using PHP, converted to lowercase and then written to a jquery array.

Checking that array using `console.log(username)` shows :

```
["bob", "brian", "charlie", "mike", "dave", "simon", "lincoln", "reg", "bill"]
```

The rule I'm using is:

```
    jQuery("#name").validate({
        expression: "if ($.inArray(VAL.toLowerCase(), username)!==-1) return true; else return false;",
        message: "username is already in use"
    });
```

Yet I never seem to get the results expected. Looking at the array I can see reg is in use, but if I enter REG or reg etc in the form field, It doesn't match the array. If I enter Phil then I get told that is in use, when it's not.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

This works.. why ?

```
expression: "if ($.inArray(VAL.toLowerCase(), username)<=-1) return true; else return false;",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think its a syntax error

try to change=>

from--

if ($.inArray(VAL.toLowerCase(), username)!==-1)

to---

if ($.inArray(VAL.toLowerCase(), username)!=-1)

Comment: That is not a syntax error. _If I enter Phil then I get told that is in use_....this line in post says that is working but there might be issue with name "reg"

Comment: Hi changing to `!=-1` hasn't helped.  But changing to this has :
`expression: "if ($.inArray(VAL.toLowerCase(), username)<=-1) return true; else return false;",`  why ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that `username` is not in the scope of the expression. You could do `document.username = username` and use document.username in the expression.